# Implement cache using closure

Tags: javascript, caching, closures

I want to implement a cache-like closure that cache the results to perform faster. e.g imagine two numbers are given and the purpose is to return the multiply of them, first we look at the cache whether it is calculated before or not, if so it returns the value quickly, otherwise it should be calculated and saved in the cache.

Here is what I've implemented:

```
var Obj = {
    h(x, y) {
        return x + y;
    },
    slow(x, y) {
        alert('called slow function with ' + x + ', ' + y);
        return x * y * this.h(x, y)
    }
}

function c (func){
    var cache = {};
    return function(x, y){
        if (!cache[[x, y]]){
            cache[[x, y]] = func(x, y);
        }
        return cache[[x, y]];
    }
}

Obj.slow = c(Obj.slow);
alert(Obj.slow(1, 4));
alert(Obj.slow(1, 2));
alert(Obj.slow(1, 4));
alert(Obj.slow(1, 3));
alert(Obj.slow(1, 2));
alert(Obj.slow(1, 3));
```

I don't know why it doesn't work. I would be thankful if anyone could help me.
The error is at line 7 with `this` keyword.

> TypeError: this.h is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` in slow method when call is run in the context of window so it doesn't have `h` method avaiable. `bind` the context to `Obj` will make it work.

Updated code

```
var Obj = {
    h(x, y) {
        return x + y;
    },
    slow(x, y) {
        alert('called slow function with ' + x + ', ' + y);
        return x * y * this.h(x, y)
    }
}

function c (func){
    var cache = {};
    return function(x, y){
        if (!cache[[x, y]]){
            cache[[x, y]] = func(x, y);
        }
        return cache[[x, y]];
    }
}
Obj.slow = Obj.slow.bind(Obj); // You have to bind the object slow method to object context

Obj.slow = c(Obj.slow);
alert(Obj.slow(1, 4));
alert(Obj.slow(1, 2));
alert(Obj.slow(1, 4));
alert(Obj.slow(1, 3));
alert(Obj.slow(1, 2));
alert(Obj.slow(1, 3));
```